# Zuul url mapping with spring boot,Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am building Rest api using microservice architecture. I have multiple apis for user that we have made into multiple projects. I have everything else ready except I am not able to map the user facing url to the application url in zuul.

The user facing url is : user/v1/accountholders/{id}/cards and the actual url for my application is /user-cards/v1/accountholders/{id}/cards.

Here id is the path variable. Below are other similar api url so if there is a way to configure them generically in zuul. Also the context root of the application url is also the project name in Eureka.

```
Other similar urls are:

client side:- /user/v1/accountholders/{id}/cards/{cardid}
application:- /user-cards/v1/accountholders/{id}/cards/{cardid}

client side:- /user/v1/accountholders
application:- /user-cardholder/v1/accountholder

client side:- /user/v1/accountholders
application:- /user-cardholder/v1/accountholder

client side:- /user/v1/accountholders/{id}
application:- /user-cardholder/v1/accountholders/{id}

client side:- /user/v1/accountholders/{id}/accounts
application:- /user-accounts/v1/accountholders/{id}/accounts

client side:- /user/v1/accountholders/{id}/accounts/{accid}
application:- /user-accounts/v1/accountholders/{id}/accounts/{accid}
```

Need some help to set this up in the properties or yml file for zuul. I havent been able to make any progress with the mapping stuff yet. Any inputs will be helpful.

**SOLVED:-**
After getting the input from @Daniel (which is the accepted answer)This is what i used in zuul config:-

```
zuul:
 routes:
   User-Cards: 
        path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/cards/**
        url: http://desktop-uvkv1ed:9999/user-cards/v1/accountholders
   User-Transactions1: 
        path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/transactions
        url: http://desktop-uvkv1ed:5555/user-transactions/v1/accountholders
        service-id: User-Transactions
   User-Transactions2:  
        path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/accounts/*/transactions
        url: http://desktop-uvkv1ed:5555/user-transactions/v1/accountholders
        service-id: User-Transactions
   User-Accounts: 
        path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/accounts/**
        url: http://desktop-uvkv1ed:7777/user-accounts/v1/accountholders
   User-Cardholders: 
        path: /user/v1/accountholders/**
        url: http://desktop-uvkv1ed:8888/user-cardholders/v1/accountholders
```

Comment: At first glance I don't think what you want is currently possible, though a pull request to support regex's in mappings should land soon. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/699

Comment: Can you help me with the approach that i can use i can play with the application url but not the user facing url so that i can perform the mapping easily.

Comment: @spencergibb Actually this is possible cause in essence all goes back to a subclass of `AbstractUrlMappingHandler` that does support ant-style pattern matching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to achieve what you are trying to do by giving the correct Zuul config. Lets assume you have the user-cardholder service running on port 8081 and the user-account service on 8082 so that you can successfully answer requests going against:

```
http://localhost:8081/user-cardholder/accountholders/{id} 
http://localhost:8082/user-account/accountholders/{id}/accounts/{accid}
```

If this is working then you can achive what you are trying for these two services by using the following zuul config:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    cardholder:
      path: /user/accountholders/*
      url: http://localhost:8081/user-cardholder/accountholders/
    account:
      path: /user/accountholders/*/accounts/**
      url: http://localhost:8082/user-accounts/accountholders/
```

Unfortunately you will also have to add more configs – even when they go against the same backend service – due to the fact that internal and external urls are differing. Otherwise you could just add the option `stripPrefix: false` and use the same internally as externally.

Comment: THanks Daniel.. This helped a lot